# Disable submit after sending request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I know, there are already a couple of topics on stackoverflow about this, but trust me I have tried everything and nothings working for me so I had to post this topic

The issue is, sometimes it takes around 30 - 40 secs to process and submit form and users tend to multiple clicks on the submit button. Because of this multiple requests are send and data gets inconsistent

I need some how to disable the submit button **after sending the post request** only once till the page refreshes!

My platform is ASP.NET MVC - SQL Server

My html:

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{               
input type="submit" name="@mo" value="Save" id="Save" class="btn" />
}
```

Below is the jquery I am using, but its not working. Multiple clicks are still happening.
Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {


        $("form").submit(function () {
            $(this).submit(function () {
                return false;
            });
            return true;
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried: `$("input,button").attr("disabled", true)` ?  Or simply adding a flag: `var flag=false; if(flag) return false; flag = true; return true; `

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am not really good at frontend scripting, actually I am just sql developer, can you give me reference links, where is the submit handler written?

Comment: Checkout this reference https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-disable-submit-button-after-clicked-with-jquery/

Comment: @Wocugon Aside from Google Searching `Javascript How to write a submit handler.` or `JavaScript event handler tutorials` etc.. there is the [**MDN JavaScript Guides**](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) and documentation too.

Answer (score 4):

Disable the submit button in your submit function:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $("#Save").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `return false` with flag which will be responsible for status of your form. If this flag is `true` when just don't submit form anymore. Also add `sending` flag to prevent multiple form submit.

```js
var $form = $('form'),
  $button = $('button', $form),
  $progress = $('#progress'),
  sending = false, // Ajax status
  submited = false; // Submit status


$form.on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default to be able to send ajax request
  if (submited || sending) return; // If already submitted or in process, end here
  sending = true;
  
  $progress.css('display','block')
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    success: function(){
      submited = true;
      sending = false
      
      $button.attr('disabled', true);
      $progress.css('display','none')
    },
    error: function(){
      sending = false
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form'>
  <input type='text' />
  <button>Submit</button>
  <div id='progress' style='display:none'>Loading</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Probably best to immediately set `submitted = true` right away to prevent multiple clicks before success is triggered and on error set it to false, or use 2 separate variables or even better disable the button right away and re-enable it on error.

Comment: @Nope Yeah, you are right, just forgot it. But it's better to have two separate variables to control ajax process and submit status. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just copy paste. just replace your JavaScript code above into this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function () { 
  $("form").submit(function (e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#Save').prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).submit();
 }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Above is the shortcut for you. but when I read this:

> The issue is, sometimes it takes around 30 - 40 secs to process and
> submit form and users tend to multiple clicks on the submit button.
> Because of this multiple requests are send and data gets inconsistent

I really think that hide submit button is not the way out to solve your issue. this will cause you post another thread with similar question again. so doing this (hide button) is useless.